Nav2 to navigate to space outside of global cost map when using static layer
Does anyone know if there is a way to travel to goal poses outside of the global cost map while using nav2 with static layer enabled? When I set up a SLAM simulation with nav2, the initial slam map is quite small and the static layer resizes the global cost map to this shape, which doesn't allow me to set goal poses that are outside this small map. When I deactivated the static layer, my robot doesn't avoid obstacles coming from the slam map anymore but is able to travel to poses further away. Any help would be appreciated!

You could set the width and height parameters of the global costmap to a high number.
The default is a 5x5 (meters) costmap.
parameters are listed here

To traverse regions outside the global costmap boundaries you need to set this param to true
track_unknown_space: true

